# Active Directory User Management with F#

Tags: f#, active-directory, crud

I have been looking into **F#** for quite a while now in between projects at work, but never really had the guts to start using it in any of them. Usually just **fall back to C#** when working with .net.

I am currently planning an automated user management application, basically CRUD between a database and Active Directory. I am at a point where I am willing to use F# as I believe that data handling would work much better and I won't have much of a GUI, only a logging interface in the background.

My question is at this point if anyone with prior knowledge to F# would advise me to go full throttle with this language for a project like this. I am **not asking** if it is better or not to use the language itself, but if it is advisable as is, or better to just plug in some scripts here and there. Or if F# is a no go for a project like this especially for someone who had a term of Scala and only wrote some math functions in different ways possible in F#. This project has a dead line, too.

Just afraid that if I don't start using the language in a real project soon that i never will.

Comment: Pretty much anything you could use C# for, you can use F# for. I say go for it.

Comment: Got the answer I was looking for from Stephen Swensen as he has prior experience with a project. Don't believe it's opinionated as I didn't know it was possible to modify the active directory efficiently and I explicitly wrote: I am not asking if it is better or not to use the language itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, my first production (in professional capacity) F# code bits involved querying Active Directory and stuffing the results into a SQL Server database. It worked out very nicely, so I say go for it!

Some pleasant points I remember:

- I created some F# record types to project raw ldap results into... pattern matching on the record types was a boon.
- I implemented an implementation of the dynamic operator `?` for accessing the properties of the ldap results in a less stringy way.
- I used SQL Server's bulk copy ADO.NET feature for efficient large inserts of ldap into the database.  F# allowed me to create clean, easy abstractions that hid some of the ugliness of the raw ADO.NET API.
- I implemented these backend F# bits in a standalone project which was consumed by a C#-based APS.NET  MVC project (mostly to push a button to execute some action). Interop with C# was pretty nice (I did have to expose a more C# friendly API, if I recall, but it was simple and easy).
- F# interops with .NET APIs like a champ, so no issues there with the ldap API
- F# is fun and reduces defect density!

Comment: giving you the answer due to the answer being much closer to my question. Sounds great!

Answer (score 1):

I myself, would definitely give it a try, as the code seems to be very maintainable even by people who do not have deep knowledge of F#.

My opinion might be slightly biased, though, as I very much like F# myself. But I did have the opportunity to introduce F# at work to my team of C# developers, who had had no F# knowledge at all.

We started off with a few coding dojos, where after a quick language intro, the team managed to write more unit tests and complete more of the coding kata, than ever before in C#, even though they are new to F#. And this consistently over the last four coding dojos now.

Also we rewrote our build scripts in F# - we had used powershell scripts before. And this encouraged us to go way beyond the complexity of the old build scripts. And it is a fact, that the team now feels like the code is very maintainable, even though they have a limited knowledge.

Actually, it has been such a successful endeavour, that we are now putting real thought into writing some imporant core components in F#.

Comment: So you started slow in your team. Was the dojo code used for anything or just sparring?

Comment: Well, we made the TennisScorer, BowlingScorer, RPN calculator and KataPotter. They are just for sparring, but we started rewriting our build scripts after like the first or second kata. And the build scripts are used productively and even shared amongst 3 teams.

Comment: Also, you have to consider, that I suggested, we'd give it a try and I introduced it. It was not like we as a team had decided to try F# and then I introduced, but I showed it to people and deferred the decision whether or not to give it a try until they knew enough about it to make an intelligent decision. Therefore I went slow.